# Posting a JS multidimensional array to PHP via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, multidimensional-array

I have an ecommerce site and I am trying to set up shipping zones in the US by state. To do this I have created a drag and drop system where we have 8 shipping zones and you can just drag the states into the appropriate zone.

This is kind of working as expected but I have a few issues:

1. When you have dragged a state into a zone and drag another state on top of it it gets nested within the state rather than the drop zone, so is there a way that if it gets dropped onto another state it gets added to the parent zone? `JS line 9-12`
2. When I try to send this across to my PHP script it is not getting picked up properly. The `console.log()` before the ajax bit shows the multidimensional array as I want it, but I get the `post_set_blank` blank response.

For this my PHP script is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['shipping_zone_array']) && $_POST['shipping_zone_array']!=""){
    echo 'session_set';
}else if(isset($_POST['shipping_zone_array'])){
    echo 'post_set_blank';
}else{
    echo 'not_posted';
}
```

Code:

```js
function drag_start(event) {
 event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
 event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.getAttribute('id'));
}

function drag_drop(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 var elem_id = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 if(event.target.className == 'states'){
  console.log('in another state');
  event.target.parent.appendChild(document.getElementById(elem_id));
 }else{
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(elem_id));
 }
}

var zone_1 = [];
var zone_2 = [];
var zone_3 = [];
var zone_4 = [];
var zone_5 = [];
var zone_6 = [];
var zone_7 = [];
var zone_8 = [];
var shipping_zone_array = [];

function readDropZone(){
 var shipping_zones = document.getElementsByClassName("shipping_zone");
 for(var i=1; i<=shipping_zones.length; i++){
  var shipping_zone = document.getElementById("shipping_zone_"+i);
  for(var j=1; j<=shipping_zone.children.length; j++){
   alert(shipping_zone.children[j].id);
   if(i==1){
    zone_1.push(shipping_zone.children[j].id);
   }else if(i==2){
    zone_2.push(shipping_zone.children[j].id);
   }else if(i==3){
    zone_3.push(shipping_zone.children[j].id);
   }else if(i==4){
    zone_4.push(shipping_zone.children[j].id);
   }else if(i==5){
    zone_5.push(shipping_zone.children[j].id);
   }else if(i==6){
    zone_6.push(shipping_zone.children[j].id);
   }else if(i==7){
    zone_7.push(shipping_zone.children[j].id);
   }else if(i==8){
    zone_8.push(shipping_zone.children[j].id);
   }
  }
 }
 shipping_zone_array['zone_1'] = zone_1;
 shipping_zone_array['zone_2'] = zone_2;
 shipping_zone_array['zone_3'] = zone_3;
 shipping_zone_array['zone_4'] = zone_4;
 shipping_zone_array['zone_5'] = zone_5;
 shipping_zone_array['zone_6'] = zone_6;
 shipping_zone_array['zone_7'] = zone_7;
 shipping_zone_array['zone_8'] = zone_8;
 
 console.log(shipping_zone_array);
 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("shipping_zone_array", shipping_zone_array);
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
   if(this.responseText.includes('session_set')){
    console.log('session_set');
   }else if(this.responseText.includes('post_set_blank')){
    console.log('post_set_blank');
   }else if(this.responseText.includes('not_posted')){
    console.log('not_posted');
   }
  }
 };
 xmlhttp.open("POST", "mypage.php", true);
 xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
```

```css
.states{
 display:inline-block;
 background-color:#CCC;
 border:1px solid #999;
 border-radius:3px;
 width:100px;
 height:40px;
 margin:5px;
 padding:5px;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:middle;
 cursor:move;
}
.shipping_zone{
 display:inline-block;
 background-color:#EEE; 
 border:1px solid #999;
 border-radius:5px;
 width:650px; 
 height:220px;
 margin:5px;
 padding:5px;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
  <div id="shipping_zone_1" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 1<br /></div>
  <div id="shipping_zone_2" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 2<br /></div>
  <div id="shipping_zone_3" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 3<br /></div>
  <div id="shipping_zone_4" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 4<br /></div>
  <div id="shipping_zone_5" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 5<br /></div>
  <div id="shipping_zone_6" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 6<br /></div>
  <div id="shipping_zone_7" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 7<br /></div>
  <div id="shipping_zone_8" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 8<br /></div>
 </td>
 <td>
  <div id="AL" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Alabama</div>
  <div id="AK" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Alaska</div>
  <div id="AZ" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Arizona</div>
  <div id="AR" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Arkansas</div>
  <div id="CA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">California</div>
  <div id="CO" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Colorado</div>
  <div id="CT" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Connecticut</div>
  <div id="DE" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Delaware</div>
  <div id="FL" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Florida</div>
  <div id="GA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Georgia</div>
  <div id="HI" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Hawaii</div>
  <div id="ID" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Idaho</div>
  <div id="IL" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Illinois</div>
  <div id="IN" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Indiana</div>
  <div id="IA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Iowa</div>
  <div id="KS" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Kansas</div>
  <div id="KY" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Kentucky</div>
  <div id="LA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Louisiana</div>
  <div id="ME" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Maine</div>
  <div id="MD" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Maryland</div>
  <div id="MA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Massachusetts</div>
  <div id="MI" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Michigan</div>
  <div id="MN" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Minnesota</div>
  <div id="MS" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Mississippi</div>
  <div id="MO" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Missouri</div>
  <div id="MT" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Montana</div>
  <div id="NE" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Nebraska</div>
  <div id="NV" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Nevada</div>
  <div id="NH" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">New Hampshire</div>
  <div id="NJ" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">New Jersey</div>
  <div id="NM" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">New Mexico</div>
  <div id="NY" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">New York</div>
  <div id="NC" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">North Carolina</div>
  <div id="ND" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">North Dakota</div>
  <div id="OH" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Ohio</div>
  <div id="OK" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Oklahoma</div>
  <div id="OR" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Oregon</div>
  <div id="PA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Pennsylvania</div>
  <div id="RI" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Rhode Island</div>
  <div id="SC" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">South Carolina</div>
  <div id="SD" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">South Dakota</div>
  <div id="TN" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Tennessee</div>
  <div id="TX" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Texas</div>
  <div id="UT" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Utah</div>
  <div id="VT" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Vermont</div>
  <div id="VA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Virginia</div>
  <div id="WA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Washington</div>
  <div id="WV" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">West Virginia</div>
  <div id="WI" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Wisconsin</div>
  <div id="WY" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Wyoming</div>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>

<center>
<button onclick="readDropZone()">Get Object Data</button>
</center>
```

Comment: Ok so never mind the first part I just had the wrong syntax `parent` instead of `parentElement`

Comment: Does the data show up in the POST request in the network tab of the browser? Aka, is the problem on the PHP or the JS side?

Comment: @Shilly thanks for your comment, hadn't even checked there, it's being posted blank in the console, so it appears to be a JS issue.  But like I said the `console.log()` before the request shows what I want to send.

Comment: Do I need to serialize the array or something to send it as a post?

Comment: Maybe. I would not use a FormData() but just stringify the array into JSON and then send the JSON string. But both methods should work, so there's something going wrong with that part I think. Hence I asked what the network tab shows. If you see an empty body, there's something going wrong with the FormData(), if the network request shows the correct body, something like `shipping_zone_array=[{"key":"val"}]&type=multipart/form-data`, then the issue is with your PHP.

Comment: What is the actual response text your PHP returns to the browser? Is it the error text? What is the value of `$_POST['shipping_zone_array']` when the PHP script is running, before you send a response back to the AJAX?

Comment: I changed it to `console.log(shipping_zone_array);var shipping_array = JSON.stringify(shipping_zone_array);var formData = new FormData();formData.append("shipping_zone_array", shipping_array);` but now it just sends `shipping_zone_array=[]'

Comment: Your array population script does not work. Trying to find the bug, but when you open the console, you see that you get an error that the id is not readable. So your array is empty because there's bugs in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shipping zones HTML `<div id="shipping_zone_1" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 1<br /></div>` also contains a `<br>` tag.

When you loop over the children, `for(var j=1; j<=shipping_zone.children.length; j++) {`, you also encounter the `<br>` tag inside the children collection.

When you then ask for the id of that `<br>` tag, you get an error, since they do not have an id. The result is that your arrays stay empty.

So either filter out the nodes that aren't `<div>` tags or use a different array creation method.

I would use a simple function that immediately selects the correct tags - and only the correct tags, nothing else - by using `querySelector()` looking for all elements with the class `.states` inside the zone element, instead of `getElementById()` the zone and then loop the children.

```js
function drag_start(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.getAttribute('id'));
}

function drag_drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var elem_id = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  if(event.target.className == 'states'){
    console.log('in another state');
    event.target.parentElement.appendChild(document.getElementById(elem_id));
  }else{
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(elem_id));
  }
}
function get_states( zone_selector ) {
  return Array
    .from( document.querySelectorAll( `${ zone_selector } > .states`))
    .map( state => state.id );
}
function readDropZone(){
  var shippping_zones_object = {
    "shipping_zone_1": get_states( '#shipping_zone_1' ),
    "shipping_zone_2": get_states( '#shipping_zone_2' ),
    "shipping_zone_3": get_states( '#shipping_zone_3' ),
    "shipping_zone_4": get_states( '#shipping_zone_4' ),
    "shipping_zone_5": get_states( '#shipping_zone_5' ),
    "shipping_zone_6": get_states( '#shipping_zone_6' ),
    "shipping_zone_7": get_states( '#shipping_zone_7' ),
    "shipping_zone_8": get_states( '#shipping_zone_8' )
  };
  console.log( shippping_zones_object );
  // Continue with AJAX.
}
```

```css
.states{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:3px;
    x-width:100px;
    x-height:40px;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:move;
  }
  .shipping_zone{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#EEE; 
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:5px;
    x-width:650px; 
    x-height:220px;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <div id="shipping_zone_1" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 1<br /></div>
    <div id="shipping_zone_2" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 2<br /></div>
    <div id="shipping_zone_3" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 3<br /></div>
    <div id="shipping_zone_4" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 4<br /></div>
    <div id="shipping_zone_5" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 5<br /></div>
    <div id="shipping_zone_6" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 6<br /></div>
    <div id="shipping_zone_7" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 7<br /></div>
    <div id="shipping_zone_8" class="shipping_zone" ondragenter="return false" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false" ondragleave="return false" >Zone 8<br /></div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div id="AL" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Alabama</div>
    <div id="AK" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Alaska</div>
    <div id="AZ" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Arizona</div>
    <div id="AR" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Arkansas</div>
    <div id="CA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">California</div>
    <div id="CO" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Colorado</div>
    <div id="CT" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Connecticut</div>
    <div id="DE" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Delaware</div>
    <div id="FL" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Florida</div>
    <div id="GA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Georgia</div>
    <div id="HI" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Hawaii</div>
    <div id="ID" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Idaho</div>
    <div id="IL" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Illinois</div>
    <div id="IN" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Indiana</div>
    <div id="IA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Iowa</div>
    <div id="KS" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Kansas</div>
    <div id="KY" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Kentucky</div>
    <div id="LA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Louisiana</div>
    <div id="ME" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Maine</div>
    <div id="MD" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Maryland</div>
    <div id="MA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Massachusetts</div>
    <div id="MI" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Michigan</div>
    <div id="MN" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Minnesota</div>
    <div id="MS" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Mississippi</div>
    <div id="MO" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Missouri</div>
    <div id="MT" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Montana</div>
    <div id="NE" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Nebraska</div>
    <div id="NV" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Nevada</div>
    <div id="NH" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">New Hampshire</div>
    <div id="NJ" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">New Jersey</div>
    <div id="NM" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">New Mexico</div>
    <div id="NY" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">New York</div>
    <div id="NC" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">North Carolina</div>
    <div id="ND" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">North Dakota</div>
    <div id="OH" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Ohio</div>
    <div id="OK" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Oklahoma</div>
    <div id="OR" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Oregon</div>
    <div id="PA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Pennsylvania</div>
    <div id="RI" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Rhode Island</div>
    <div id="SC" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">South Carolina</div>
    <div id="SD" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">South Dakota</div>
    <div id="TN" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Tennessee</div>
    <div id="TX" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Texas</div>
    <div id="UT" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Utah</div>
    <div id="VT" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Vermont</div>
    <div id="VA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Virginia</div>
    <div id="WA" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Washington</div>
    <div id="WV" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">West Virginia</div>
    <div id="WI" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Wisconsin</div>
    <div id="WY" class="states" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" ondragend="return false">Wyoming</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="readDropZone()">Get Object Data</button>
```

**PS**: If you still want to do the two for-loops, `.children` only gives me the BR tags. You need `.childNodes` inside your for-loops if you want to do it this way.

**PPS**: If you set `shipping_zone_array['zone_1'] = zone_1;`, you technically want an object with arrays as proeprties, instead of a multidimentional array. So either change the name or use the correct syntax.

Multi array would be:

```
[
 [ "IL", "MI" ],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 []
]
```

Object would be:

```
{
  "zone_1': [ "IL", "MI" ],
  "zone_2': [ "IL", "MI" ],
  "zone_3': [ "IL", "MI" ],
  "zone_4': [ "IL", "MI" ],
  "zone_5': [ "IL", "MI" ],
  "zone_6': [ "IL", "MI" ],
  "zone_7': [ "IL', "MI" ],
  "zone_8': [ "IL", "MI" ]
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I just get a blank object `shipping_zone_array: [object Object]` I don't think this is the case as my array is right in the console when I log it, the `<br>` tag is always first so my loop starts at 1, the `<br>` tag would be `shipping_zone.children['0']`

Comment: Then you have to JSON.stringify() the object before sending it with AJAX. There is also a textnode before the <br>, so depending on if you use .children or .childNodes, you have to starts at 2 instead of 1. Anyways, good luck then.